# How do I check to see if a resource exists in Android

Tags: java, android

Is there a built in way to check to see if a resource exists or am I left doing something like the following:

```
boolean result;
int test = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("my_resource_name", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
result = test != 0;
```

Comment: It don't seem a very hard way to do this. What's bothering you in this method ?

Comment: Perhaps not, but I like built-ins that do the error handling for me, rather than sticking try/finally everywhere.

Comment: You do not need any error handling here. Read my comment below.

Comment: Just for reference to anyone looking at this, the code above would always leave result as `false` anyway.  That's the whole point of `finally` - it doesn't mean "if there was an error", it means "always"

Answer (score 69, accepted):

According to the javadoc you don't need the try catch:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

if `getIdentifier()` returns zero, it means that no such resource exists.
Also 0 - is an illegal resource id.

So your result boolean variable is equivalent to `(test != 0)`.

Anyway your try/finally is bad, because all it does it set the result variable to false even if exception is thrown from the body of try: `mContext.get.....` and then it just "rethrows" the exception after getting out of finally clause. And I suppose that is not what you want to do in case of exception.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: What if I have "my_resource.png" and "my_resource.xml"? How can I difference them between each other?

Answer (score 41):

The try/catch block in your code is totally useless (and wrong), since neither [`getResources()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29) nor [`getIdentifier(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) throw an Exception.

So, [`getIdentifier(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) will already return you all you need. Indeed, if it will return 0, then the resource you are looking for does not exist. Otherwise, it will return the associated resource identifier (["0 is not a valid resource ID"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), indeed).

Here the correct code:

```
int checkExistence = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("my_resource_name", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());

if ( checkExistence != 0 ) {  // the resource exists...
    result = true;
}
else {  // checkExistence == 0  // the resource does NOT exist!!
    result = false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

i like to do something like that:

```
public static boolean isResource(Context context, int resId){
        if (context != null){
            try {
                return context.getResources().getResourceName(resId) != null;
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException ignore) {
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

so now it's not only for drawable

Comment: Does it actually throw the NotFoundException?

Comment: yeah ! i cannot find i Id that does no exist

Comment: well, just try an arbitrary number such as 666. If 666 exists, loop through from 1000 to 5000, there should be some IDs in there which doesn't exist as Resources.

Comment: The problem with this method (as is, anyway) is in the scenario where the resource value doesn't exist as a Drawable, but exists as a String. If you were checking for a Drawable, you just caused a crash.

Answer (score 6):

In case someone is wondering, the `"my_resource_name"` in

```
int checkExistence = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("my_resource_name", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
```

is actually

```
String resourceName = String.valueOf(R.drawable.my_resource_name);
int checkExistence = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName , "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
```