# How can I check if a file xml in my resources exist?

Tags: java, android

I have tried this code:

```
int checkExistence = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("file", "values", mContext.getPackageName());

if ( checkExistence != 0 ) {  // the resouce exists...
    result = true;
}
else {  // checkExistence == 0  // the resouce does NOT exist!!
    result = false;
}
```

But always the result is false. Does anyone know another method?

Thanks ;)

Comment: you mean a file inside layout?

Comment: I mean for example a file "settings.xml" in values folder.

Comment: I assume you already saw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539630/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-resource-exists-in-android If it's always returning false... it's because it doesn't exist or you're using the wrong name