# Check for Value folder in android

Tags: android

As we all know that we have values folder arranged depending on language selected for example `value-en`, `value-ja`.
I just want to check whether the specific value folder exists or not?
For example i want to check `value-fr` is present or not in `res` folder?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539630/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-resource-exists-in-android)?

Comment: @EricB. I think that OP wants to check if specific localization exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to define boolean item in `values/localized.xml` (or some other resource file like `strings.xml`):

```
<resources>
    <bool name="localized">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Then override it in each `values-xx` folder:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="localized">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Now you can create `Resource` object for specific locale and check `localized` resource value:

```
Resources currentResources = getResources();
AssetManager assets = currentResources.getAssets();
DisplayMetrics metrics = currentResources.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration config = new Configuration(currentResources.getConfiguration());
config.locale = Locale.FRENCH;
Resources localizedResources = new Resources(assets, metrics, config);
if (localizedResources.getBoolean(R.bool.localized)) {
    // values-fr exists
}
```