# MediaPlayer.setDataSource() doesn't catch exception

Tags: android, uri, android-mediaplayer

I would like to catch an exception if the audio file read by the mediaplayer does not exist. From a URI, I've got the following code:

```
try{player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri); }

    catch (IllegalStateException e) {Log.e("MUSIC", "Error setting data source", e);}
    catch (IOException e) {Log.e("MUSIC", "Error setting data source", e);}
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e){ Log.e("MUSIC", "Error setting data source", e); }
    catch(SecurityException e){ Log.e("MUSIC", "Error setting data source", e); }

player.prepareAsync();
```

However, it seems the exception is never raised, even with a bad URI. 
I am probably missing something obvious here, but what is the best way to catch an exception so as not to launch the reading if the uri does not exist?

Comment: Please comment or explain if you vote down a question

Comment: @Mishra What do you mean? There is no caught exception.

Comment: Why do you want it to throw an exception? What is the problem with the current code? Why don't you simply previously check if the file exists?

Comment: @J Yes good idea. But it seems that the function .setDataSource was also designed for this purpose, doesn't it?

Comment: Why do you call prepareAsync() outside of try block? What does happen when bad uri is send? Did you try to call setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)  before setDataSource?

Comment: I tried setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) without success. And I try to call prepareAsync() in the try block also.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, thanks to the comment of J, to test if the file exists. As the file are in my raw folder, it is a little bit tricky. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19002535/3244382) to solve it.

At the end, my code looks like :

```
file_name ="name_of_the_ressource_whitout_directory_or_extension";
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + file_name);

int checkExistence = getResources().getIdentifier(file_name, "raw", getPackageName());

if (checkExistence != 0){

        // The audio file exists

        try{
            player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            player.prepareAsync();
        }

        catch (IllegalStateException e) {Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);}
        catch (IOException e) {Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e); }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e){ Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);  }
        catch(SecurityException e){ Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e); }
```

Note that I am not sure about the utility of the try/catch now.