# How to check if resource exists?

Tags: java, android

I have a code like this

```
int resid = getResources().getIdentifier(somestring +"_1", "array", getPackageName());
```

And i want to check if this resource exists before using it(or do some other code). Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: if resid != 0.....is it what u want?

Comment: Hmm... I've tried but i got NPE. Seems that my problem is in other code string. Thanks anyway

Comment: **Or you can check this link** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539630/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-resource-exists-in-android

Answer (score 1):

According to Android doc:
[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

If the resource does not exist. it will be return 0 value. so check if your resource id != 0, it's exist.