# How to verify that Android Layout Resource Xml exists in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a layout in my Xamarin Android project.  I want to confirm that the resource is actually present in build.

I tried the following code:

```
var layout = Resources.GetLayout(Resource.Layout.my_xml_resource);
var xml = layout.ReadInnerXml();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(xml);
```

The `GetLayout` call does not throw the `NotFoundException` so presumably the resource exists.  However, layout object, upon inspection, displays `None`.

[image]

The `xml` variable is empty and all attempts to read the xml are unsuccessful.

I am down this rabbit hole, because I am trying to use the layout with `Inflate`. Unfortunately, the output of inflate does not have the child controls I would expect and I suspect the resource layout is empty.

`nativeView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_xml_resource, view, true);`

What am I missing?  Is there another way to verify the resource exists?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539630/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-resource-exists-in-android

Comment: I'll take a look and see if I can derive the .NET equivalent of that Java code.

Comment: The other question simply aligns with the notion that there is no "NotFoundException" however it does not help verify that the contents of the resource are present.

Comment: If getIdentifier (`Identifer`) returns `0`, the layout is invalid/NotExist as all valid/found/inflated layouts have to an `id` greater then `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Resources.GetIdentifier(String, String, String) Method` could verify that Android Layout Resource Xml exists or not.

In C#, you could try the code below. If the resId not be 0, the resource exists.

```
int resId = Resources.GetIdentifier("textlayout", "layout", "com.companyname.app1");
```

**textlayout**: This is the layout name of my project, please note it need lower case.

**layout**: The type of resource you want to verify. It need lower case as well.

**com.companyname.app1**: PackageName, you could get from the AndroidManifest.xml file.
[image]

Comment: I guess this is sufficient, but I would like to be able to actually read the xml of the layout resource.  Per this answer, I did get a `0` for the resource at runtime.  It turns out my problem is that the resource is in a library project and apparently is not getting merged into the UI project at runtime.  I guess that is a separate question, so I will mark this answered.